# How to predict the next pixel given all previous pixels in an image using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, recurrent-neural-network

Just as a project, I wanted to see if it would be possible to predict the next pixel in an image given all previous pixels.
For example: lets say I have an image with *x* pixels. Given the first *y* pixels, I want to be able to somewhat accurately predict the *y+1th* pixel. How should I go about solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for some kind of generative model. RNNs are commonly used, and there's a great blog post [here](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) demonstrating character-by-character text generation.

The same principle can be applied to any ordered sequence. You talk about an image as being a sequence of pixels, but images have an intrinsic 2D structure (3 if you include color) that would be lost if you took the exact same approach as text generation. A couple of ideas:

1. Use tensorflow's [GridLSTMCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/GridLSTMCell)s
2. Treat a column of pixels as a single element of the sequence and predict column-by-column (or row by row)
3. Combine idea 2 with some 1D convolutions along the column/row
4. Use features from a section of an image as the seed to a [generative adversarial network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2661). See [this repository](https://github.com/jackd/gan_tf) for basic implementations.